# Proper way of killing forked child process(es)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm working on an Express app where I need to fork an expensive process, and kill the process when it's complete.

I've seen varying ways to do this on Stack Overflow and searches, but I would like to know if this is the proper way to do it when using the `child_process.fork(...)` methodology.

```
// route handler - /routes/api.js

exports.redirect = function(req, res) {
    var campaignId = req.query.campaignId,
        destination = req.query.destination,
        worker = child_process.fork(__dirname + '/../workers/redirect');

    worker.send({
        campaignId: campaignId,
        destination: destination
    });

    worker.on('message', function(msg) {
        this.kill();
    });

    return res.redirect(destination);
};



// forked process file referenced as "worker" - /workers/redirect.js

var db = require('../db'),
    RedirectedUrlService = require('../services/redirect'),
    logger = require('../logger');

process.on('message', function(data) {
    RedirectedUrlService.create(data, function(error, redirectedUrl) {
        if (error) {
            logger.log('error', error);
        }

        process.send('done');
    });
});
```

I'm not seeing any additional worker references if I: `ps ax | grep node`, so it seems to be doing what I expect.

Is this correct, and my code is still non-blocking? or by messaging the parent to issue the `kill()`, have I completely defeated the purpose of creating the fork in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child process, use `process.exit(0);`

Comment: Well, that was easy. I also found this module: https://github.com/Kop4lyf/child-process-manager to limit the number of `child_process` instances. Thank you! I really need to take the time to read the Node documentation more thoroughly.